# how to have a dynamic response for a simple http server python

Tags: python

I created an http server in directory on port 8000
on the browser as soon as I call `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` I have all the files in the directory, but if I want to display an `index.py` page as I did before with Php, I can't display the page correctly it opens as a notepad but on browser

here is the program of my server

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
Handler.extensions_map.update({
                              '.webapp': 'application/x-web-app-manifest+json',
                              });

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "Serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

and here is the programme for `index.py` , `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

when I contract the page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.py`, I have a note block that opens gold that I want a html page

Comment: SimpleHTTPServer doesn't do CGI. You need CGIHTTPServer, please see the docs for details. BTW, those module names have changed in Python 3.

Comment: thank you man, it's different than NODEJS or Php with Apach ,

Comment: SimpleHTTPServer and CGIHTTPServer are ok for testing and for private work, but they don't provide much in the way of security, so if you intend to expose your server to the real Internet then you should use a proper server like Apache. It's pretty easy to configure Apache to accept .py files as CGI scripts.

Comment: it's just a small project to order a robot on a website using JavaScript and ajax, thank's men